# How to use border-image for IE browser

Tags: php, jquery, internet-explorer, css

I want to use `border-image` in IE.

I know `border-image` is a css3 tag and that is not supported in IE, but can we use this with some external jQuery/JavaScript function.

**Please help me**

Answer (score 1):

Check PIE CSS3 library http://css3pie.com/documentation/supported-css3-features/

PIE adds support for the border-image property to IE 6-9. This property allows you to specify an image which gets divided into nine squares which are then drawn as the corners, sides, and center of the target element.